# Allign product category to top in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one small problem with my Woocommerce shop.

Currently into [my shop](https://phoenixfitness.dk/butik/) when check from smartphone(small) screen widths, its showing ***Product category*** widget to top, but I want to place it to top.

This is CSS that I get from that element:

```
.sidebar.widget_area .sidebar_inner.widget_area_inner {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Can someone to help me how to position that widget to top of shop page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have Markup structure in such a way that pushes your widget `sidebar` to below. As in markup you have `content` as first child and `sidebar` widget as second(next) child.

There are two possible solutions to this:

**1.** *CSS* properties for specific mobile screens. ***[Prefreable]***

**2.** *Rearranging your HTML Markup*.

---

## CSS Solution

You can use display flex properties targeting small screen size, which as follows:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .content_wrap {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .sidebar_left .sidebar.widget_area {
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order:1;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
  .sidebar_left .content {
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order:2;
  }
}
```

> You can place above CSS code at line no. 878, of `responsive.css` file. Right before your media query for screen width below 767px starts.

---

## HTML Solution

You can swap your elements having class `.sidebar` and `.content` inside your `content_wrap`.

[image]

Hope the answer helps you out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, your CSS do the job, seems that not moving category sidebar to top. .I still see on bottom.. I added code on line number 878, of responsive.css file. Its strange because when add your CSS into responsive.css, widget is still on bottom, and when add CSS to Wordpress Custom CSS editor then widget is as should be on top, but page content is misalligned. Can you take a look?

Comment: Hey, I assume you have placed that code in `responsive.css` file at mentioned line, and if I see it looks perfect to me in mobile screens and large screen widths. This is the [screenshot](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-449b5b664c.gif) for the same. Check it out. If you still find issues there might be your browsers cache issue.

Comment: Probably was cache. Now is fine. :) Thanks

Comment: Sounds weird, but after cleared cache i see format like this:

Comment: Oh, so it got bad again or it solved now? Didn't got you.

Answer (score 1):

Product category widget is coming down because in html its order is below the content div.

Currently the div structure is like this

```html
<div class="content_wrap">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar widget_area scheme_original">
  </div>
</div>

Change this to this foramte

<div class="content_wrap">
  <div class="sidebar widget_area scheme_original">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```